# Installing python 2.7.2 on a network drive (MAC OSX)

Tags: python, mac-osx

I'd like to install python on a network drive to ease the job of keeping all users on the same  version of python.

The 'readme' which accompanied the download from python.org suggests I must install onto the current boot disk for things to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might go about installing on a network drive (mounted over NFS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure, build and install Python with

```
./configure --prefix=/where/you/want/python
make
sudo make install
```

then tell all users to include `/where/you/want/python/bin`, or rather its local name on the NFS clients, to their `PATH`, OR make sure that `/where/you/want/python` is mounted at `/usr/local` on each host ([union mounts](http://aplawrence.com/foo-mac/union-mounts.html) are very useful for this).

Comment: Thanks. Union mounts seem a great solution but I am struggling with the syntax

Comment: Thanks.@larsmans  mount -t nfs -o union 111.111.1.11:media/RT0/tools/SITE/software/OSX /user/local gives the following error mount_nfs: can't access media/RT0/tools/SITE/software/OSX: Permission denied

Comment: @user993269: sounds like you need to execute `mount` as root.